# Compile error: constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I want to initialize instance variables with constructors but I get a compile error.

```
class Test{


    public static void main(String[] args){

        A a = new A(5,6);
        System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}

class A{
    int i, k;
    A(int a, int b){
        this.i=a;
        this.k=b;   
    }
}

class B extends A{
    int k;
    B(int a, int b, int c){
        this.k = a;
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Test.java:26: error: constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;
        B(int a, int b, int c){
                              ^
  required: int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your problem is that you cannot construct an object B without constructing first an object A. If you had a default constructor in A, you wouldnt need to call super in B ( it will be automatically called though ).

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `super` call in `B`. You can fix it by using

```
class B extends A{
    int k;
    B(int a, int b, int c){
        super(a,b);
        this.k = a;
    }
}
```

Also you probably meant to use `this.k = c`.

Comment: ok, thanks it works but it is compulsary to initialize parent variables in child constructor.

Comment: @Dr.Sikandar no.